# Calc always have to zoom in!

Tags: libreoffice

Every time when I open new document in Libre Office Calc, the cells are too small so every time I have to zoom in with CTRL+scroll wheel UP;  (See the picture below)

[image]

How can I set the most acceptable view for me (but not only for one document, I want larger cells every time I open new blank document)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Close all CALC windows
- open a new one
- Go to bottom right slider and move it to 100% (or whatever value you need)
- Close CALC
- open it again; cells are now in correct size :)

you can also do it from Menu > View > Zoom

Comment: that was easy :D

Comment: @Wilf Anytime :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> View and reset the Scaling option to 100%. Yours appears to be set at 22%.

To quickly reset the scaling for any open sheet, double-click on the display percentage at the bottom-right of the window (next to the scaling slider) to bring up the Zoom & View Layout dialog.

Comment: - Minimum value for above mentioned option is 80% and it will affect scaling allover CALC.
- Correct answer is to manually change Zoom level (not scaling) either manually from the slider or from Menu > View > Zoom

Answer (score 2):

What you describe makes me think of a broken template. I'd suggest to create a new one and set it as your default Calc template:

- Open a Calc document, adjust the zoom level to 100%
- Save the document by choosing File - Save As Template and saving the document in the My Templates category.
- Choose File - New - Templates.
- Double-click My Templates in the list. You will see the user-defined templates in the user directory specified under Tools - Options - LibreOffice - Paths. Select the template you have just saved.
- Choose Set as default. The next time you open a new Calc document, the new spreadsheet will be based on the new default template.